# Can we use spacy with MXnet

Tags: spacy, mxnet

Can we use spacy with MXnet to build a deep neural network(NLP)

We are building an application using mxnet. How to use spacy with Mxnet

Comment: I don't think there is an interface in mxnet to deal with spacy model. It's easier to directly build module with mxnet.

Comment: thanks  kevinthesun

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Spacy and MXNet serialize their models differently so they are not directly compatible.

You can leverage the pre-trained models of Spacy as part of a preprocessing step for your text data though, and then feed into an MXNet model. Aim to get your text data into an NDArray format (using `mx.nd.array`).

Also take a look at MXNet's Model Zoo (https://mxnet.apache.org/model_zoo/index.html) which contains a number of models for NLP tasks; Word2Vec embedding being one example.